# Como darle focus a un boton en HTML

Tags: html, jquery

Como hago para darle el focus a un boton luego de que tengo un formulario con varios botones
[image: Este es mi formulario]

Por ejemplo hago clic en Coca Cola 12 Onz. ese es un boton pero luego quisiera que el boton verde que dice Guardar (ENTER) cada vez que selecciono un producto obtenga el foco, como hago esto?

Este es el modal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo del modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-venta">
```

×
        Informacion de la orden

```
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left btn-cerrar-imp" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat btn-print"><span class="fa fa-print"></span> Imprimir</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content -->
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambiar HTML

```
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left btn-cerrar-imp" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button id="btnImprimir_modal_ventana" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat btn-print"><span class="fa fa-print"></span> Imprimir</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Con esto al dar click en un botón, da foco al segundo

```
$('#MainButton').on('click',function(){
 $('#modal-venta').modal('show');
 $('#btnImprimir_modal_ventana').focus();
});
```

Comment: Y si quiero que el foco lo tome un boton de una modal que sale despues de darle en el boton guardar como lo haria?

Comment: Lo mismo, pero lo pones luego de lanzar el modal

Comment: y como haria eso?

Comment: Arriba coloque el modal

Comment: Muéstrame el código del modal

Comment: Lo pondre arriba

Comment: Disculpa la demora, ya edite la respuesta.